# Mysqli con php guarda todos los datos vacios

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

He solucionado el error del "undefined index" con los `if`, lo que pasa ahora es que me guarda datos vacíos en la base de datos, sin los `if` me da error e igual los guarda vacíos, ven algo que yo no?

Este es el formulario, el `select` es nada mas de un combo que tengo.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php')
?>
<body>
  <form action="guarda_usuario.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <h1>CONTACTO</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="nombre" id=""  <br>    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu apellido" name="apellido" id=""> <br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu email" name="email" id="" > <br>
    <textarea placeholder="Escriba su comentario" name="comentario"></textarea> <br>
    <select style="width:200px" name="juego" > 
      <option value="0">Selección:</option>
      <?php
      $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM productos");

      while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'">'.$valores[producto].'</option>';
      } ?>
    </select> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="" id="boton">
  </form>
</body>
```

Este es mi código para ingresar los datos a la base de datos:

```
<?php 
include('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
} else {
  $nombre = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['apellido'])) {
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
} else {
  $apellido = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
  $email = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['producto'])) {
  $producto = $_POST['producto'];
} else {
  $producto = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['comentario'])) {
  $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
} else {
  $comentario = "";
}

$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, email, producto, comentaro) 
  VALUES ( '$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$producto', '$comentario' )
  ";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a los indices de un array necesitas que sean una cadena de texto por ejemplo:

$valores["id"]  $valores["producto"]

Sólo te faltaban las comillas.

Comment: lo intente amigo y no me funciono, actualice mi codigo, ya no me da error del index, pero me sigue guardando datos vacios(null) al igual que antes, la unica diferencia es que sin el error......

Comment: tal ves no se puede establecer la conexión con la base de datos o no se reciben correctamente los datos. Puedes hacer hacer un  ***echo var_dump($_POST);*** para ver con detalle los indices y datos que recibe la página. Si los indices están en blanco, el archivo con el formulario puede tener un error

Comment: Al igual no dejes que se guarden valores en blanco con el else, usa mejor null para que la base de datos te dé el error (en el entorno de desarrollo)

`$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre'])) ? $_POST['nombre'] : null;

...`

Comment: lo que paso es que tenia el enctype=text/plain, eso me guardaba los datos en blanco, gracias de cualquier manera y suerte